# Default name for dired copy and rename

Tags: dired

I wonder if it is possible to change the following functions:

- dired-do-rename
- dired-do-copy

such that when I operate on a single file, it prompts the selected file's name as the default target name.

Most of my files have long names, when I copy/rename a file, I usually copy/rename it to a similar name. It's painful to type the entire name or copy it from the original file.

Thanks a lot for any suggestions!

Comment: Hm... tangent, but take a look at [`wdired-mode`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Wdired.html). It's awesome.

Comment: What about typing the first letter then TAB key, to auto insert the source name, then move your cursor wherever necessary for modifying the name?

Comment: Related: [Similar question about copy/rename when doing `C-x C-w`](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/2849/115).

Comment: The first answer solves my problem. The function we need to call is M-n: (next-history-element)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The ability to set the "copy to" or "rename/move to" name same as the original name is already built in.

1. Initiate the copy or move (rename) in dired
2. **(only for `ido` users)** `C-f` or `C-x C-f` - kick out of ido mode
3. `M-n` - That will give you the current file/dir name

*General tip that applies everywhere in emacs: Whenever you are hunting for a default that you think should be present, try out `M-n` or `M-p`.*