# spacemacs keeps matching my new file name to an existing file. How to save a brand new file?

Tags: spacemacs, completion

This is my example:

I have two files in a directory:

- Order.coffee
- OrderCart.coffee

I wan to save the content of `Order.coffee` to a new file `Cart.coffee`

I use `C-x C-w` to save. When I typed in `Cart.coffee`, spacemacs matches to another file within the same folder, `OrderCart.coffee`.

I am unable to save it to `Cart.coffee`.

How can I prevent this mapping?

[image]

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of this: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2849/save-current-file-with-a-slightly-different-name ?

Comment: I can't tell from the screenshot if you're using helm or ivy?  (in ivy the answer is `C-M-j`, dunno the answer for helm)