# Save current file with a slightly different name in Helm

Tags: helm, files, minibuffer

This is the same question as [Save current file with a slightly different name](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2849/save-current-file-with-a-slightly-different-name), but for Helm. (The top answer given for the original question doesn't work in Helm, sadly: `M-n` (`next-history-element`) doesn't do quite the same thing as in vanilla Emacs.)

The question is: how can I insert the filename of the current buffer into the minibuffer during `write-file`. So for example:

`C-x C-w` (this gets me to a minibuffer prompt with the current directory); in plain Emacs I could type `M-n` and this would insert the current filename for me to edit to a slightly different name. What can I do instead in Helm?

Comment: Is `M-n` bound to `next-history-element` or is it bound to something else? IOW, is `next-history-element` refedfined by helm to do something different? And if so, should that not be considered a bug in helm?

Comment: `M-n` is bound to `next-history-element`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing like it in Helm AFAIK, so I tried to mimic what
`C-x C-w M-n` does with the following command. The difference is
you have to press `C-j` (instead of `M-n`) to expand the
filename.

```lisp
(defun helm-write-file ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((filename (helm-read-file-name
                   "Write file: "
                   :preselect (when (buffer-file-name)
                                (helm-basename (buffer-file-name))))))
    (write-file filename)))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-w") 'helm-write-file)
```

Alternatively, you can skip the Helm interface with:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'helm-completing-read-handlers-alist '(write-file . nil))
```

Comment: OK, so this works fine with `C-x C-f`, but not with `C-x C-w`.

Comment: Press `C-x C-f C-j`, make your changes then `RET`. It should create a new file in the current directory.

Comment: I'm baffled, sorry! I don't want to create a new file, I want to write an existing buffer under a new name.

Comment: In that case it's `C-x C-f M-R C-j`. BTW you can also skip the Helm interface with `(add-to-list 'helm-completing-read-handlers-alist '(write-file . nil))`, in which case `C-x C-w M-n` should do what it does in vanilla Emacs.

Comment: `C-x C-f M-R C-j` renames a file, it does not write a buffer under a new name, which creates a copy. Thanks for the second tip, but I'd rather use Helm.

Comment: Phew. Sorry about that. I changed the answer. Let me know if that gets you any closer.

Comment: Thanks very much for your heroic efforts! I think before marking this as the answer, I would like to understand why, as @NickD queried, simply pressing `M-n` does not work in Helm as it does in plain Emacs.

Comment: I see that Helm development has been suspended, so no point filing a bug there, as I was going to do. I'll accept this answer as the best I'm likely to get! Thanks again.

Comment: Could be a bug (cc @xuchunyang). For example, if a buffer is not visiting a file then its name is inserted in the minibuffer (as it does without Helm). If the buffer *is* visiting a file then it fails to insert its name. Either way someone has to go down the rabbit hole.

Answer (score 0):

Bring up helm's file name history buffer with (`helm-write-file` followed by) `C-c h`.  With a bit of luck, the file name you want is at the top.  Select it with `F2`.

Note:  To edit the filename, you need to navigate with `C-f` and `C-b` in the minibuffer.  Using the arrow keys does not work for me.  (The same caveat applies to [the other answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/62819/13054).)

Comment: Thanks for your alternative simpler answer. I think you mean `C-b` not `C-p`? I prefer something I can engrave in muscle memory; "With a bit of luck" is not quite that.

Comment: Yes, corrected.